# Allowing New Users to Invite Their Gmail Contacts

Tags: gmail

For my site, I would like to give new users the option to invite all of their Gmail contacts to join.

What is the basic step-by-step process to set this up?

(Also, is it necessary to buy an SSL for this?)

Thanks in advance,

John

**EDIT:** My site has a basic login where users set up a username and password.  I would like to give users the option to invite their Gmail contacts right after they create their new profile.  I would also like to give them the option to invite their Gmail contacts anytime they want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Google Contacts Data API](http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/).